How to "unmelt" a dataframe
I have a dataframe that looks like this
GEO_NAME CHARACTERISTIC_NAME  C1_COUNT_TOTAL  C2_COUNT_MEN+  C3_COUNT_WOMEN+
60010188       0 to 14 years           105.0           50.0             50.0
60010188      15 to 19 years            30.0           15.0             15.0
60010188      20 to 24 years            20.0           10.0             15.0
60010188      25 to 29 years            35.0           15.0             20.0
60010188      30 to 34 years            35.0           15.0             20.0

Here GEO_NAME is a geographic area, and CHARACTERISTIC_NAME are the names of the variable, with the total count, men count and women count per geography. I would like to turn the dataframe from long to wide, so something like this where each geography is just one row and all of the columns are then appended.
GEO_NAME 0 to 14 years_TOTAL 0 to 14 years_MEN 0 to 14 years_WOMEN 15 to 19 years_TOTAL ...
60010188                 105                50                  50                   30 ...
....

How would I do this in pandas?

you can using pivot:
example:
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index='GEO_NAME', columns='CHARACTERISTIC_NAME', values=['C1_COUNT_TOTAL', 'C2_COUNT_MEN+', 'C3_COUNT_WOMEN+'])

# Flatten the MultiIndex columns
df_pivot.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df_pivot.columns.values]

# Reset index if needed
df_pivot.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(df_pivot)

